# Cypress Redirect To Incorrect (new url)

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to test the submission of a form. However, when I submit the form and wait/check for an element the form navigates to an new/incorrect domain. Example:

Form URL: https://formsenv.test.co.uk/IdentityDocuments/Submission/Index

Page it tries it navigate to: (new url) https://sts.test.co.uk/IdentityDocuments/default/Thankyou

It looks like it's taking the base url from the browser url field (screenshot - had to redact some info)

[Screenshot of runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l92iE.png)

Quick code snippet:

```
cy.get('[id="submitButton"]').click()
```

//Commented out as this didn't help...I tried to wait for the request to see //if I was requesting the 'cy.get('[id="thankyou-details-panel"]')' element //too early

```
//cy.intercept({
    //method: 'GET',
    //url: '/IdentityDocuments/default/Thankyou',
  //}).as('dataGetFirst');

// Wait for response.status to be 200
//cy.wait('@dataGetFirst').its('response.statusCode').should('equal', 200)

cy.get('[id="thankyou-details-panel"]').should('contain','Thank you for completing the ID verification / Right to Study form. You will be notified if there are any issues with the document(s) provided.')
```

any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: please add your code that you tried in the question.

Comment: @AlapanDas I've added the bit of code which I'm clicking the button and then 'trying' to do the check on the next page but I just get a 404 as the page does exist on the domain it's trying to use. It does exist on the 'formsenv' domain.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.